# Setup UILocalNotification with information from another object in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm making an app that is essential a timer (counts down to zero).

I have a class tracking the time, left to zero. Lets call it TimeBack.

When the user sends the app to the background via applicationDidEnterBackground, i would like to setup a UILocalNotification with a fireDate of data+timeBack.

How do i get the information from a object, to my AppDelegate so i can configure a localNotification based on the state of an object?

Comment: ok I added an answer then with more detail and a best practise solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a singleton by exposing a class method and using the `dispatch_once` method to make sure it only gets created once.

Like so:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static myObject *shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```